# Different program result depending on how program is linked

Tags: fortran, intel-fortran

I'm working on a large-ish numerical simulation program, mainly written in Fortran, that is compiled with Intel Fortran compiler (v18.0.3).

Recently, I have come across a mysterious issue: if I link the program with the external libraries as absolute paths, the numerical results are slightly different when compared to the program linked with `-L/path/to/lib -lnameOfLib`

I have checked the following:

- runtime loading of shared libraries: I checked with `strace` and in both cases the same libraries are loaded and they are loaded in the same order;
- unitialized variables: when compiled with `-check all -ftrapuv` there are no warnings or errors;
- both binaries were run with valgrind and no memory issues were found, other than in external libraries;
- the binaries are different when using `diff` on them.

I am out of options to check why this happens. I would be glad if someone could suggest further how to deal with this problem and where the differences could originate.

Comment: At least the the last time I checked the Intel compiler was not capable of catching all uninitialized variables - so that would be my guess. Do you have access to the NAG compiler?

Comment: Unfortunately no access to the NAG compiler.

Comment: -ftrapuv doesn't do anything useful, and the name is misleading. Don't bother with it. I also suspect uninitialized variables or argument mismatches. Consider adding "-warn interface" and rebuild.

Comment: When you write "results are slightly different", is this the last digit or two is different?  Can it be explained by numerical round-off or the foibles of floating point arithmetic?

Comment: I'm not sure if it's purely numerical roundoff, but ultimately during one of the test cases the differences are in the third decimal and due to these differences also the number of iterations until convergence is reached is off by one.

Comment: @SteveLionel The compilation was done with `-warn all` and showed a few warnings about unused variables only.

Comment: I have narrowed it down to the standard 'm' lib. If I link with `-lm` I get one result, if I link with `/usr/lib64/libm.so` I get the other results. When I look at symbol binding at runtime, I see that when `-lm` is used, symbols like `floor`, `cos`, `tan`, etc. are bound to /usr/lib64/libm.so, whereas when I link with the absolute path to the math library, the symbols somehow end up inside the binary and are bound to the binary itself.

Comment: In the one case, `nm ./program` shows `U floor@@GLIBC_2.2.5` whereas the other case shows many entries for `floor`: `T __libm_floor, D__libm_floor_chosen_core_func, __libm_floor_dispatch_table, __libm_floor_e7, __libm_floor_ex, __libm_floor_y8` etc.

Comment: Is `/usr/lib64/libm.so` the same library as referenced by `-lm`? Check your $LD_LIBRARY_PATH and try `locate`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm going to conclude the following, based on [this explanation](https://software.intel.com/en-us/articles/putting-lm-before-user-objectslibraries-on-link-line-can-impact-performance). When linking with /usr/lib/libm.so, the platform `libm.so` will be used. When linking with `-lm`, the Intel compiler will alter the linking command to also link the Intel math library `libimf.so`. Apparently, these different implementations will give numerical roundoff error leading to the differences.